# Interface error while working with SQL using sql connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I wanted to run my code which uses sqlconnector, but I can't,
my code:

dbconnection.py

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="yusharthsingh",passwd="xxxxxxxxx")
```

My Terminal inputs and output:

```
(ritconda) yusharthsingh@pop-os:~/Documents$ python dbconnection.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yusharthsingh/anaconda3/envs/ritconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yusharthsingh/Documents/dbconnection.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="yusharthsingh",passwd="fcukdwrld")
  File "/home/yusharthsingh/anaconda3/envs/ritconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yusharthsingh/anaconda3/envs/ritconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/yusharthsingh/anaconda3/envs/ritconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/home/yusharthsingh/anaconda3/envs/ritconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/home/yusharthsingh/anaconda3/envs/ritconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 511, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

Comment: Error `2003` usually means that no MySQL Server was found at the location you've specified. Have you confirmed that MySQL is running on the local machine *and* is listening to port 3306?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a number of reasons. The most often cited one (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55790121/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost3306-even-though-mysqld-is-running ) is a small config problem: MySQL does not listen to `localhost` but to `127.0.0.1`.  Could your try this?